# Qual a forma correta de utilizar um pacote instalado pelo npm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, front-end, npm

Para explicar minha pergunta vou utilizar como exemplo o jquery.
Instalei o jquery a partir do npm (npm install jquery). Então o npm criou a pasta node_modules\jquery\dist onde está o arquivo do jquery que preciso (jquery.js).

Para utilizar este arquivo devo apontar para esta pasta do node_modules?
Ou seja se a pasta do meu projeto está no mesmo nível da pasta node_modules devo fazer isso para utiliza meu js?:

```
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js">
```

Criei um arquivo .js tanto na pasta do meu projeto como na pasta do mesmo nível da pasta node_modules e tentei importar assim:

```
var $ = require('jquery')
```

porém não funciona. Qual seria a forma correta de fazer isso?

Comment: Sergio, até procurei se já tinha algo relacionado a minha pergunta mas não achei. De qualquer forma obrigado, esta outra pergunta respondeu a minha.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu particularmente gosto de utilizar o NPM apenas para dependências do servidor e o [Bower](https://bower.io/) para dependências do cliente.

Para instalar o Bower basta você utilizar o comando:

```
npm i bower -g
```

Após fazer isso você pode criar um arquivo chamado `.bowerrc`como está descrito [aqui](https://bower.io/docs/config/) com o local para que você instale as dependências do cliente.

O modo de utilização é semelhante ao NPM sendo que você pode gravar as dependências com `--save` e coisas assim.

**EDIT 1**

Levando em consideração o artigo [npm and front-end packaging](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/101775448305/npm-and-front-end-packaging) você pode criar outro `package.json` dentro da sua pasta `public`para suas dependências de `front-end`, mas isso não é recomendado.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas pretendo utilizar apenas o npm

Comment: @FelipeCoelho adicionei mais uma informação que talvez lhe atenda.

Answer (score 0):

A forma como você carregou o jQuery no primeiro exemplo era para funcionar, exceto pelo fato que você não fechou a tag `<script>`, talvez seja esse o problema?

Exemplo funcional:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Testando jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(window).ready(function () {
      alert("Testando jQuery");
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Se ele estiver dentro da pasta `public` criada no `express`, por exemplo, não vai funcionar não.

Comment: Minha duvida não é se funciona ou não,mas sim se esta é a forma correta de usar um pacote vindo do npm